# OpenGL: Sphere slowing down framerate

Tags: python, performance, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I have a class that makes a sphere based on the passed in stack count, sector count and radius. The issue is, whenever I draw the sphere, my frame-rate drops from 57-60 fps to 20 fps.

This is how I draw my sphere:

```
    def draw_edges(self):
        """Draws the sphere's edges"""
        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslate(self.position[0], self.position[1], self.position[2])
        glRotate(self.rotation[3],self.rotation[0],self.rotation[1],self.rotation[2])
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        for edge in self.edges:
            for vertex in edge:
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
        glEnd()
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)
        glPopMatrix()
```

Does anyone know how I could speed that up?

Comment: for loops can be quite slow in Python. Maybe there is a way to replace the two for loops.

Comment: Note that you're using the deprecated fixed function pipeline.  Although obviously supported on your system it's probably far from optimal.  You should consider moving to a programmable shader based alternative.

Comment: Or at least display-lists or VBOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get rid of the nested loops. See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) for a modern way of drawing meshes by the use of a [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) and [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).

---

Another (deprecated) possibility is to use fixed function attributes.

[OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 10.3.3 Specifying Arrays for Fixed-Function Attributes; page 402](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf#page=430&zoom=100,168,658)

> The commands
>
> ```cpp
> void VertexPointer( int size, enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void NormalPointer( enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void ColorPointer( int size, enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> [...]
> ```
>
> specify the location and organization of arrays to store vertex coordinates, normals, colors, [...]  An individual array is enabled or disabled by calling one of
>
> ```cpp
> void EnableClientState( enum array );
> void DisableClientState( enum array );
> ```
>
> with array set to `VERTEX_ARRAY`, `NORMAL_ARRAY`, `COLOR_ARRAY`, [...], for the vertex, normal, color, [...] array, respectively.

---

Create a list with the vertex attribute data in the constructor of the class:

```py
def __init__(self):
    # [...]
   
    self.vertexArray = []
    for edge in self.edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            self.vertexArray.append(self.vertices[vertex])
```

Use the array to specify the vertices and to draw the mesh:

```py
def draw_edges(self):
    """Draws the sphere's edges"""
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslate(self.position[0], self.position[1], self.position[2])
    glRotate(self.rotation[3],self.rotation[0],self.rotation[1],self.rotation[2])
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)
    
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vertexArray)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(self.vertexArray))
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)
    glPopMatrix()
```

This is the first (small) step to a modern solution with VBO and VAO.

---

A further performance improvement can be gained by the use of a [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object):

```py
def __init__(self):
    # [...]

    self.vertexArray = []
    for edge in self.edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            self.vertexArray += self.verticies[vertex] # <--- flat list

    array = (GLfloat * len(self.vertexArray))(*self.vertexArray)
    self.vbo = glGenBuffers(1)        
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

```py
def draw_edges(self):
    # [...]

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
    
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(self.vertexArray) // 3)
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you! This method doubled my framerate to a little over 40 fps.

Comment: @User-92 Thank you. You're welcome. A further improvement can be achieved by the use of a VBO. I'll extend the answer. Just one moment please...

Comment: @User-92 I've extended the answer.

Comment: Wow, That's insane! I now have over 70 fps now. I didn't know VBOs could speed up performance this much. Thank you very much!

Comment: @User-92 The trick is that the vertex array is uploaded to the GPU once, in the constructor. When you draw the object, then the array only has to be referenced. `self.vbo` is just a name id.

Comment: That's cool! It's so fast that even after setting the stack count to 256 and the sector count to 512, the program was able to run at a steady 56 fps. It looked like this:  https://s8.gifyu.com/images/results.gif (it seems slow due to the recording software being pretty bad)